# window.cofirm multiple redirection with enter key confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Here is **my code** which displays the browser confirmation window:

```
$('a[name="button-paid"]').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        window.location.href = href;
    }
});
```

Everything works fine until i tried to confirm window with **enter** key multiple times.

With multiple **enters** redirect is also triggered multiple times and my controller does his work more than once.

I fixed logic in controller to avoid multiple payments actions, but is there any way to prevent multiple redirection on client side?

Thanks.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd press is on the `a` which gets focus when the confirm window closes.

You can add `$(this).blur()` after your `event.preventDefault` to stop this.

```
$('a[name="button-paid"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).blur()
```

If you have a form, then you might also be posting your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag for this. I am not sure but might be this can help...

```
$('a[name="button-paid"]').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var flag= true;

    if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) 
    if (flag){
        flag=false;
        window.location.href = href;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button-paid').on('click', function(event) {
  // remove focus from link
            $(this).blur();
     event.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @DanielLagiň, please upvote or mark this correct, for another user who may face same problem in future.

Comment: @Sudhakar I know answers in comments is bad practice, but sometimes it's worth confirming the issue first, via comments.  Give a guy a minute before you start pressuring for points.

Comment: Also, please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300694/what-to-do-with-code-only-answers-in-low-quality-posts-queue